# How to transfer money from a paysafe card to Paypal or debit cards

Tags: debit-card, paypal, payment

The question is pretty straightforward but I'll put some background to it:
I got a paysafecard to make a purchase from an online site that no longer supports this way of payment. I'd like to transfer the money from the paysafecard to my debit card or even my Paypal account, if possible.

PS: Not sure if I'm asking the question on the correct community, or even if any community supports these type of questions.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to ask for a refund of the Paysafecard credit to your bank account.

From there, you'll be able to use a debit card associated to your bank account, or transfer it to Paypal.

Here's the form to request the refund:

https://customer.cc.at.paysafecard.com/customerrefund/start.xhtml

You may have to provide copies of ID and proof of address, and there will be a 7.50 euro fee for the refund.